# How can I make an "area selector" in C#?

Tags: c#, select, desktop, capture, area

Exactly like [this](http://www.farooqazam.net/draw-a-rectangle-in-c-sharp-using-mouse/), but without the limitation on the form and I need to be able to get the rectangle coordinates.

Appreciate every bit of help!

Comment: Something like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21913/TeboScreen-Basic-C-Screen-Capture-Application) maybe?

Answer (score 0):

I hope You are able to draw Rectangle by following the code given in your link. 
[Draw Rectangle](http://www.farooqazam.net/draw-a-rectangle-in-c-sharp-using-mouse/)

Now, You want to get coordinates X,Y, Left, Right.
Add the new lines below in Form1_Move.

```
 private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
 {
     if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
     {
       Rect = new Rectangle(Rect.Left, Rect.Top, e.X - Rect.Left, e.Y - Rect.Top);
                label3.Text = Rect.Left.ToString();
                label4.Text = Rect.Top.ToString();
                label1.Text = e.X.ToString();
                label2.Text = e.Y.ToString();
     }
            this.Invalidate();
 }
```

Comment: I need to be able to make a rectangle outside the form.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? you want to make a 'selection' of the part of the 'screen' or what?